# .NET BackGroundWorker - InvalidOperationException : Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a project coded in .NET Winforms.
I need to implement a data-mining operation, print the text to TextBox and update the progress.

I tried to use BackgroundWorker to do, but it throws a InvalidOperationException (**Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ‘xxxxx’ accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on**)

To narrow down the potential causes of the problem, I started a new project, included the following:
Button -  To start the BackgroundWorker
Label - to print the text.
And ProgressBar.

However, the result is the same. I searched on SOF, and was told to use a delegate, but I  am not familiar with it.

This is the code sample that throws the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _bw.DoWork += RosterWork;
            _bw.ProgressChanged += BwProgressChanged;
            _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BwRunWorkerCompleted;
            _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        }

        private void RosterWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                label1.Text = i.ToString();
                _bw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((i * (100 / 1000))));
            }
        }

        private void BwProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Show();
            _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void BwRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Hide();
        }

    }
}
```

**Update:**
I follow Jon Skeet's answer, it really work on my test project, but back to my real project,

The Layout of my Form:

Form -
   TabControl
     - Tab1 
       -Tab1Panel
       -TextBox1

When reach this line :

```
TextBox txtbox1 = new TextBox();
Tab1Panel.Controls.Add(txtbox1);
```

The error still occur when i add Textbox to Panel Control Programmatically.

Finally,I replace by this:

```
 if (Tab1Panel.InvokeRequired)
     Tab1Panel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Tab1Panel.Controls.Add(txtbox1); });
 else
     Tab1Panel.Controls.Add(txtbox1);
```

Everything is work. How to determine the control is InvokeRequired, Is it control specified?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
label1.Text = i.ToString();
```

You're trying to change the label text within the `BackgroundWorker`, which is not running on a UI thread. The point of `BackgroundWorker` is to do all the non-UI work there, using `ReportProgress` to periodically "go back" to the UI thread and update the UI with the progress you're making.

So *either* you need to change `label1.Text` in `BwProgressChanged` as well, *or* you need to use `Control.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` just as you would from any other background thread:

```
// Don't capture a loop variable in a lambda expression...
int copy = i;
Action updateLabel = () => label1.Text = copy.ToString();
label1.BeginInvoke(updateLabel);
```

For more about the copying part, see Eric Lippert's blog post, ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). In this particular case it's only an issue because I'm using `BeginInvoke`. This *could* be changed to just:

```
Action updateLabel = () => label1.Text = i.ToString();
label1.Invoke(updateLabel);
```

... but now the background worker would always be waiting for the UI to catch up before it kept going, which in real life is *usually* not what you want. I generally prefer `BeginInvoke` over `Invoke`.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet! I search on Google about .NET Threading. I read some article about Thread/ThreadStart/ThreadPool/Delegate. It seems all of them is more like expected standards on thread programming. So is it right ways to use BackgroundWorker?

Comment: @Shiba: I'm afraid I don't really understand your comment - particularly "all of them is more like expected standards"...

Answer (score 5):

use this code iw will work

```
 BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
               {
                   TextBox1.Text += "your text here";

               });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing your label - which has been created on the GUI thread - from within your backgroundworker-thread.
Accessing a Windows control from a thread other than on which the control has been created, is not allowed; therefore you're given the exception.

You should not access the label directly, but instead you should raise an event from within your thread, - and make sure it's invoked on the correct thread - that signals the UI so that you can change the content of the label.

Answer (score 0):

You must execute the methods of a control from the thread that has created them. To update them from a different thread use [Invoke](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28VS.80%29.aspx). An example of how this can be done can be found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35616-cross-thread-communication-in-c#/). You should also read [Multithreading with Forms and Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32y8wtd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN.