# Get richtextbox.text from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I can't believe this hasn't been asked before but I can't find a reference here. Sorry if I've missed it!! There's plenty on updating rtb.Text from a thread but little or none on getting rtb.Text.

I need to get the text value from a richtextbox on the UI thread from another thread and later be able to loop through each line of the same richtextbox.

I guess Invokes and Delegates are required but how to craft them??

As an example the code, if it was in the same thread, would be something like:

```
private void checkRtbEntries()
{
    if (rtb.Text != "")
    {
        foreach (string textLine in rtb.Lines)
        {
            // do some things in the background thread 
            // based on the rtb line content...
        }
    }
}
```

But, checkRtbEntries() is called from within a Backgroundworker thread and rtb is in the UI thread, hence a Cross-thread operation not valid is thrown.

Comment: Just from a quick search on: "C# cross thread get control value"... it's a similar question but different control. Take a look for an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086676/cross-thread-operation-is-not-valid-exception-when-trying-to-get-value-of-comb

Comment: Thanks, I didn't spot that, maybe as I searched for the problem rather than the error message. It seems a bit of an overkill. There must be a simpler way??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run your BackgroundWorker thread, you have the option of passing an argument to it, which the other thread can reference and use:

```
myWorker.RunWorkerAsync(rtb.Text);
```

Inside the `DoWork` event, cast the argument back to a string and perform your actions on it.

```
var myRtbText = e.Argument.ToString();
```

This way, your background thread never actually touches the UI thread.

If you need to make changes to an element back on the main thread *while* your background worker is running, you'll need to use the `ProgressChanged` event.

Since you don't have a reference to the `RichTextBox` in the `DoWork` event (just the contents of its `Text` property), you can't actually call the `Lines` property on the original text box.

You should be able to simulate it pretty easily though (the actual `Lines` property tests for "\r", "\r\n", and "\n", but `Environment.NewLine` should take care of figuring that out for you):

```
var allLines
    = myRtbText.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

*(Or use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries if you want to ignore blank lines.)*

Comment: Thanks but whilst this may be useful sometimes I don't think it will allow the `foreach (string textLine in rtb.Lines)` to work. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I've tried your code but I still get the error "String does not contain a definition for 'Lines'..."

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. Oh, I had to replace `Environment.NewLine` with `"\n"` and after that all was well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual way to jump from the background to the UI thread (for every control)

```
 private delegate void checkRichTextBoxDelegate(); 
 private void checkRtbEntries() 
 { 
     if (this.rtb.InvokeRequired) 
     { 
         checkRichTextBoxDelegate checkEntries = new checkRichTextBoxDelegate(checkRtbEntries); 
         this.Invoke(checkRtbEntries); 
     } 
     else 
     { 
         .... do your work on the RichTextBox, you are on the UI thread
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your entry but I do not want to do work on the RichTextBox. I have edited my question to reflect that the work in the loop should be within the Backgroundworker thread based on entries in the RichTextBox (If that makes sense??)